# Sum column in google viz DataTable dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, google-visualization, googlevis

Here I have an simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/36yve/

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Prepare the data
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
    ['Michael' , 'Male', 12, 5],
    ['Elisa', 'Female', 20, 7],
    ['Robert', 'Male', 7, 3],
    ['John', 'Male', 54, 2],
    ['Jessica', 'Female', 22, 6],
    ['Aaron', 'Male', 3, 1],
    ['Margareth', 'Female', 42, 8],
    ['Miranda', 'Female', 33, 6]
  ]);

  // Define a slider control for the Age column.
  var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'control1',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Age',
    'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
    }
  });

  // Define a category picker control for the Gender column
  var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Gender',
      'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false
      }
    }
  });

  // Define a Pie chart
  var pie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'PieChart',
    'containerId': 'chart1',
    'options': {
      'width': 300,
      'height': 300,
      'legend': 'none',
      'title': 'Donuts eaten per person',
      'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
      'pieSliceText': 'label'
    },
    // Instruct the piechart to use colums 0 (Name) and 3 (Donuts Eaten)
    // from the 'data' DataTable.
    'view': {'columns': [0, 3]}
  });

  // Define a table
  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    'options': {
      'width': '300px'
    }
  });

  // Create a dashboard
  new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
      // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
      // picker will drive both charts.
      bind([slider, categoryPicker], [pie, table]).
      // Draw the entire dashboard.
      draw(data);
}
```

​all works fine.

**What I want to know?**

How I can add row at the end of table to sum column [Age and Donuts eaten] and also to work when I use filters-controls ?

is there any solution for that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the Table out of the Dashboard and create a "ready" event handler for the PieChart that grabs the data used by the chart, aggregates it to get the totals, builds a new DataTable including the totals, and draws the Table using the new data:

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Prepare the data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
        ['Michael' , 'Male', 12, 5],
        ['Elisa', 'Female', 20, 7],
        ['Robert', 'Male', 7, 3],
        ['John', 'Male', 54, 2],
        ['Jessica', 'Female', 22, 6],
        ['Aaron', 'Male', 3, 1],
        ['Margareth', 'Female', 42, 8],
        ['Miranda', 'Female', 33, 6]
    ]);

    // Define a slider control for the Age column.
    var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'control1',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Age',
            'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
        }
    });

    // Define a category picker control for the Gender column
    var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control2',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Gender',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false
            }
        }
    });

    // Define a Pie chart
    var pie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
        'containerId': 'chart1',
        'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'legend': 'none',
            'title': 'Donuts eaten per person',
            'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
            'pieSliceText': 'label'
        },
        // Instruct the piechart to use colums 0 (Name) and 3 (Donuts Eaten)
        // from the 'data' DataTable.
        'view': {'columns': [0, 3]}
    });

    // Define a table
    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'chart2',
        'options': {
            'width': '300px'
        }
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(pie, 'ready', function () {
        var dt = pie.getDataTable().toDataTable();
        var totals = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [{
            type: 'number',
            column: 0,
            // make all values the same
            modifier: function () {return 0;}
        }], [{
            type: 'number',
            column: 2,
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
        }, {
            type: 'number',
            column: 3,
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
        }]);
        dt.addRow(['Total', null, totals.getValue(0, 1), totals.getValue(0, 2)]);
        table.setDataTable(dt);
        table.draw();
    });

    // Create a dashboard
    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
    // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
    // picker will drive both charts.
    bind([slider, categoryPicker], [pie]).
    // Draw the entire dashboard.
    draw(data);
}
```

see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/x8f7J/

Comment: also I have in datatable 25 columns, so it possible to not do this:  dt.addRow([null, 'Total', null, null,null,null,null,null,totals.getValue(0, 1),totals.getValue(0, 2),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]); so is there way to put only data I know...

Comment: Look at that example, when I change pie ready to table ready: http://jsfiddle.net/x8f7J/2/ I get some errors. WHY?

Comment: If you want to do this with a Dashboard, you have to have a dummy chart of some type.  In the example you posted, you had a PieChart, so I used that.  If you remove the PieChart, you have to replace it with something else, even if the replacement is not visible to the user - I typically recommend using a Table and setting it's container div to `display: none`: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/x8f7J/3/.

Comment: The reason you cannot create the event handler on `table` is twofold: first, you need something to get the filtered data from, and since you will be changing the data in the Table, that won't work.  Second, since you are creating a "ready" event handler that redraws the Table, you would end up with an infinitely repeating cycle of draw -> fire ready event -> change data -> draw -> fire ready event -> change data -> draw...

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to know just how is this possible with larger amount of data (etc. 300 rows)? is google visuaisation datatable better that jquery DataTables? What you suggest to me to use?

Comment: 300 rows should be quite fast in most circumstances in all modern browsers.  It is possible that you could see slowdown from rendering the dummy table (it still writes to HTML even if its hidden), but you can mitigate that by setting the dummy's `view.rows` parameter to `[]`, eg: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/x8f7J/4/

Comment: Sorry but do you maybe know... Is there any possibility that Google terminate access to Google visulisation APIs, its important for me becouse I create a SaaS based on gViz API (datatables,charts,control filters...) ?

Comment: The [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms) give the policy about API availability and deprecation.  Last I read, it was guaranteed to be provided for 3 years following the date of deprecation, and the API has not been deprecated.